# How to display ArrayList in TextView?

Tags: android, arraylist, textview

[image]

Hi All,
I'm trying to create an app that shows some questions and EditText fields in front of the each of the question for an answer, at a time.  My current code provides me with all the questions in one row repeating whatever the size of the arraylist is, please see photo attached but I want the each question on each individual line, can someone please help.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdapterListView adapter;
    private Button btnStart, btnSubmit;
    private ListView questListView;
    Questions ques;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        btnStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setQuestions();
            }
        });

    }//End of create()


    public void setQuestions() {

        ArrayList<Questions> qArrList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ques = new Questions();
            ques.setQuestion("");
            qArrList.add(ques);
        }
        adapter = new AdapterListView(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_listview, qArrList);
        questListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        btnSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}//End of Class
```

Adapter

```
    public class AdapterListView extends ArrayAdapter<Questions> {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Questions> questionsArrayList;
    private Questions quesObject;
    private ArrayList<String> quesList;

    public AdapterListView(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Questions> questionsArrayList) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.setQuestionsArrayList(questionsArrayList);
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        int flag = 0;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.questionTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);
            holder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ans_edit_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        quesObject = getQuestionsArrayList().get(position);

        quesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        quesList.add("3 + 3");
        quesList.add("4 + 3");
        quesList.add("3 + 3");
        quesList.add("6 + 3");
        quesList.add("8 + 3");

        holder.questionTextView.setText("Q " + position + ": \t" + quesList);

        holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                getQuestionsArrayList().get(position).setQuestion(holder.editText.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return getQuestionsArrayList().size();
    }

    public ArrayList<Questions> getQuestionsArrayList() {
        return questionsArrayList;
    }

    public void setQuestionsArrayList(ArrayList<Questions> questionsArrayList) {
        this.questionsArrayList = questionsArrayList;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView questionTextView;
        EditText editText;
    }
}
```

Object

```
public class Questions {
String question;

public Questions() {
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter's getView() you have setting the whole question list in text view by this line of code -

```
holder.questionTextView.setText("Q " + position + ": \t" + quesList);
```

In stead you have only to show one questoion as -

```
holder.questionTextView.setText("Q " + position + ": \t" + quesList.get(position));
```

Thanks.